# Trichotomy of Ordinals. Is $K$ a set?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

We want to prove the "Trichotomy of Ordinals":

**Definiton**: An ordinal is a transitive set with elements that are all transitive.

**Definiton**: $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ordinals are comparable if one of the following is true, $\alpha \in \beta$ or $\beta \in \alpha$ or $\alpha = \beta$.

During the proof we set:

$$K=\{\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle \mid \alpha \text{  and  } \beta \text{  are not comparable  }\}$$

as the "set" of the ordered pairs of ordinals that are not comparable, and we want to show that it is empty. In order to claim that there is a minimal element in $K$ under a certain relation between ordered pairs of ordinals, it must be a set. Is $K$ a set? Why?

Thanks!

Comment: @bof Yes thanks!!!!!

Comment: $K$ is in fact a set because it's the empty set, but that's what you have to prove. No you can't *assume* that $K$ is a set. One approach would be to define $K_\gamma=\{\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle\in\gamma\times\gamma\ |\ \alpha\text{ and }\beta\text{ are not comparable }\},$ and show that the **set** $K_\gamma $ is empty for every ordinal $\gamma.$

Comment: @bof that seems good. But how can you tell that for every $\alpha$, $\beta$ there exists an ordinal $\gamma$ such that $\alpha,\beta \in \gamma$?

Comment: @Maffred : I think you can construct such an ordinal : take the transitive closure of $\{ \alpha, \beta\}$ and **remove** $\{\alpha, \beta \}$ (or else it's not an ordinal ^^)

Comment: @Tryss I thought about that, but I've never seen this move. It seems an infinite move, is that allowed?

Comment: @Maffred : it can be show that the transitive closure of a set always exists. But Here, I'm pretty sure that it's $\alpha \cup \beta \cup \{\alpha\} \cup \{\beta\}$ (because $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are ordinals), so it's easy in this case

Comment: @Tryss If I don't get wrong $\gamma = \alpha^+ \cup \beta^+ = \alpha \cup \beta \cup \{\alpha, \beta \}$ makes the job, is that right?

Comment: @Maffred : yes :)